# Blazor HTML number inputs don't enforce min max constraints

Tags: c#, blazor

I am trying to constrain the max number value a user can put into an HTML number input. This works fine if I just use the arrows to change the number, but if the user manually inputs a number, it doesn't enforce.

Is there a built in solution to this WITHOUT javascript/JQuery, or form submissions? A Blazor Component you know of, that might help? Thanks!

```
@foreach(var component in Components)
{
    <tr>

        <td>
            <input type="number" min = "1" max="Assembly.Component.Quantity" @bind-value="Component.Quantity"/>
         </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: This is not using Blazor, this is straight html. HTML inputs do not have a way to validate this without the use of javascript/jquery

Comment: Blazor does have input validation. A user does not have to submit the form to validate the input. https://blazor-university.com/forms/validation/

Comment: @AdamVincent I am using input validation throughout the application, but unfortunately, I cannot use it here due to the dynamic nature of the table.

Comment: So your question is at a higher level than this. Try and take a step back and figure out which problem you actually need to solve for, because this question, as-is, has a very straightforward and idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a control doesn't exist, build it.

Here's one based on `InputNumber` that:

1. Constrains an int value.
2. Won't let you enter a value outside the constraints.
3. Adds a validation message if you try and do so.

```cs
@using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis
@using System.Globalization
@inherits InputNumber<int?>

<input type="number" class="@this.CssClass" @attributes=this.AdditionalAttributes value=@this.CurrentValueAsString @oninput=OnValueChanged />

@code {
    [Parameter] public int Min { get; set; } = int.MinValue;
    [Parameter] public int Max { get; set; } = int.MaxValue;

    private async Task OnValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        // capture the current state
        var currentValue = this.CurrentValue;
        var resetToCurrent = false;

        // Check if we need to reset the display value
        if (BindConverter.TryConvertTo<int?>(e.Value?.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out int? value))
            resetToCurrent = value < this.Min || value > this.Max;

        // Sets off the internal InputBase update process        
        this.CurrentValueAsString = e.Value?.ToString();

        // Bit of a hoop jumping exercise to get the display value back to what it was.
        // Currently the actual UI Dom has it at the new (invalid) value
        // whilst the Render DOM has it at it's last value.
        // If we set it to it's old value the Renderer thinks it hasn't changed and doesn't do anything!
        if (resetToCurrent)
        {
            this.CurrentValue = value;
            StateHasChanged();
            // Called to yield and let the Renderer update the component before we reset it to the old value
            await Task.Delay(1);
            this.CurrentValue = currentValue;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    // Normal override to covert the string value to it's correct type and add validation message if we need to.
    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out int? result, [NotNullWhen(false)] out string? validationErrorMessage)
    {
        validationErrorMessage = null;

        if (BindConverter.TryConvertTo<int?>(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result))
        {
            if (result < this.Min)
                validationErrorMessage = $"{DisplayName ?? FieldIdentifier.FieldName} must be greater than {this.Min}";

            if (result > this.Max)
                validationErrorMessage = $"{DisplayName ?? FieldIdentifier.FieldName} must be less than {this.Max}";
        }

        if (validationErrorMessage is not null)
            result = CurrentValue;

        return validationErrorMessage is null;
    }
}
```

And my test page:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<EditForm Model=this.model>
    <MyInputNumber @bind-Value=this.model.Value Min=1 Max=10 placeholder="Must be 1-10" />
    <ValidationSummary />
</EditForm>

<div class="m-2 p-2 bg-dark text-white">
    Value : @this.model.Value
</div>

@code {
    private ModelData model = new ModelData();

    public class ModelData
    {
        public int? Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change your bind getter/setter like this.

For example, I want to enforce a min of `10` and a max of `500`:

```
private int? overrideWidth;
public int? OverrideWidth {
    get => overrideWidth;
    set => overrideWidth = value < 10 ? 10 : value > 500 ? 500 : value;
}
```

And my input:

```
<input type="number" @bind="SomeModel.OverrideWidth" @bind:event="oninput" class="form-control">
```